# Helping `magit-ediff-dwim` read my mind

Tags: magit

I found out that `magit-ediff-dwim` cannot "read my mind" in a diff buffer when the point is on a hunk.

Intuitively, I would expect this command to need only two things to guess what I mean: a file (e.g. the file of the hunk at point) and either a revision or a range. In a revision buffer, `magit-ediff-dwim` correctly guesses which revision ediff should use.

When visiting arbitrary diffs however, the function does not guess that "what I mean" is starting an ediff session using the same range as the one which defines the diff buffer.

Some scenarios to reproduce:

- `d r foo..bar` will spawn a diff buffer showing changes between revisions `foo` and `bar`;
- `d d` when point is on branch `baz` in the refs buffer will spawn a diff buffer showing changes from the current branch to `baz`;
- `d d` in the log buffer when the region spans commits `foo` to `bar` will spawn a diff buffer showing changes between revisions `foo` and `bar`.

In each of these situations, if I set the point on a hunk and call `magit-ediff-dwim`, the function fails to read my mind.

I poked around `magit-diff.el` and `magit-ediff.el` and found that I could help magit read my mind by adding the following to `magit-diff--dwim`:

```
@@ -616,6 +616,8 @@ If no DWIM context is found, nil is retu
     (cons 'commit magit-buffer-refname))
    ((derived-mode-p 'magit-revision-mode)
     (cons 'commit (car magit-refresh-args)))
+   ((derived-mode-p 'magit-diff-mode)
+    (nth 0 magit-refresh-args))
    (t
     (magit-section-case
       ([* unstaged] 'unstaged)
```

*Disclaimer: I am **not** an E?Lisp developer by any means. I just threw the above together after looking up a few symbols' documentation or `message`ing their value when trying to wrap my head around what was happening.*

Onto questions.

1. Am I missing something that would explain why `magit-ediff-dwim` should not read my mind in diff buffers, although it can in rev buffers?
2. Is this worth creating an issue on the Github tracker?
3. Is the patch above sound? I figure maybe it is not appropriate to poke around `magit-refresh-args`, or maybe another case could be added to the `magit-section-case` switch below.

Version: `20151118.241` from [MELPA](https://melpa.org/packages/).

*Additional disclaimer: sorry if I sound like I am complaining - magit is a wonderful piece of software that makes version control a very pleasant experience.*

Comment: It seems I have now placed the "don't use the issue tracker to ask questions" prominently enough. But it also seems to have had too big an effect on you in this case - here it would have been better to go directly to the github issue tracker. I would consider this either a feature request or a bug report, hell, there's code, so it could have been a pull request (though I suspect this will be a bit more involved than adding these two lines). I'll try to have a look in a few days. (And I think it's okay to keep this open in the mean time, and that there's no need to also open a feature request.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition you suggested does the job just fine. I've added them now. Sorry for the delay. It would of course be nice if this also jumped to the correct change, but that isn't implemented yet (see [issue #1566](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1566)).

Comment: Never mind the delay, thank you for taking the time to add this :) If the lack of jump ends up itching, I might start poking around again (although I suspect this itch will feel pretty minor compared to the one which got me to ask this question).